# Fixing html and css

Tags: html, css

First.. How do i fix this:
http://jsfiddle.net/kLjcq/

I am seeing this properly formatted on my browser..!

- http://picpaste.com/pics/Screenshot_from_2013-02-07_13_31_20-ViIvXLQf.1360273538.png
- http://picpaste.com/pics/Screenshot_from_2013-02-07_13_37_15-GBjeEsL8.1360273595.png

But on the fiddel it messes things up.. :( What happened? HOw do i fix this?

Second is.. if i have long string... it shoots over that light gray border of the heading 
"Reading from xml..." thingy

What I am looking for is that the maxiumum spread of this text goes upto that border.. and after that.. it breaks to a next line.. so that text is enclosed properly..

In div.content

```
div.content {
    background-color: #add8e6;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top:-5px;
}
```

I tried to add limit and stuff.. but it limits the blue box to a pixel value 
but instead i want text (and blue box) to limit upto certain limit after which it
breaks to a new line...
any clues.
Thanks

Comment: Stack overflow wasnt letting me post another link (new user here)
But here is another image which might be useful
http://picpaste.com/pics/Screenshot_from_2013-02-07_13_37_15-GBjeEsL8.1360273419.png

Comment: Posting 2 unrelated questions in a single question ends up with responses that only answer 1 question or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're absolutely positioning the `.checksheet` class. This removes it from the document flow. Other elements like your `.content`-class don't care for it.

I don't know why you use `position: absolute;` in this context, but it's producing your mistake.

Comment: Hi. Thanks :) I wish i could upvote you. but i dont have enough reputation yet. :)
Any clues on text limit thingy?

Comment: Hi.. DOes this image helps.. Trust me. the complete markup is posted on the jsfiddle..http://picpaste.com/pics/Screenshot_from_2013-02-07_13_37_15-GBjeEsL8.1360274477.png

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is breaking because you're using absolute positioning.  When the screen is narrow, your elements in the checklist are wrapping around, but the elements that follow are positioned in a way that assumes the preceding element is only 1 line instead of 2.

Without the actual markup relating to your second question, we can only guess at what the actual problem is.  However, since you're using `pre` in the sample provided, the culprit is most likely there.  What you need is to add a property like this:

```
white-space: pre-wrap
```

Without this property, the pre tag generally does not allow elements to word-wrap, which will cause it to take up as much horizontal space as possible to display all of the text.

Comment: But thats the complete markup?? Shall I specifying some sort of width along this property in pre css?

Comment: @user2052251 You only provided a fiddle for the first image, not the second.